# Apache на GitHub Pages

Tags: .htaccess, apache, github, httpd, github-pages

### 1. `.htaccess` на GitHub Pages:

Как выглядит `.htaccess` моего сайта на GitHub Pages:

```
# Переадресация index.html на заглавную
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://Kristinita.github.io/ [R=301,L]

# Скрытие расширений .html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

# Кастомная страница 404
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Содержимое `index.html` на заглавной, расширения скрываются, при ошибке 404 показывается моя кастомная страница.

### 2. Вопрос

Применимы ли правила `.htaccess` к сайтам на GitHub Pages? Ведь GitHub Pages является только хостингом для статических сайтов.

Comment: GitHub pages это не совсем хостинг, так что врядли вы сможете гибко его настроить. Он предназначен впринципе для хранения как максимум html+css+javacript

Comment: (1) Про метку [tag:github-pages] я уже всё сказал, могу только добавить, что количество вопросов по метке ни  на другом сайте сети, ни здесь не является аргументом в её пользу: Опытные участники порой бывали вынуждены отредактировать **сотни** вопросов, для удаления откровенно мусорных меток, вроде [tag:программирование], так как даже у модераторов нет инструментов массового редактирования меток, кроме синонимов, которые не всегда применимы.
(2) Изображения вставляются в вопросы, когда проще что-то показать, чем описывать. В вашем случае изображения лишь дублируют текст и раздувают вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Ответ

[image: Плохо] Настройки сервера GitHub Pages отличны от настроек сервера Apache. `.htaccess` и `httpd.conf` на GitHub Pages не применяются.

---

### 2. Обоснование

[image: Маркетинг] GitHub — очень раскрученный ресурс; если какой-то функционал есть, о нём наверняка написали бы на официальном сайте. А про Apache на сайте GitHub ничего не написано. Вряд ли маркетологи допустили бы подобное упущение.

Можно попробовать потестировать некоторые правила `.htaccess` на GitHub Pages. Положим, [**скрытие директории из URL**](http://naikom.ru/blog/archives/1693):

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(.+)$ http://www.sashagoddess.com/ [R=301,L]
```

или [**отображение кастомного html-файла на заглавной странице сайта**](http://www.blogerator.org/page/fajl-primery-htaccess-redirekt-dostup):

```
DirectoryIndex SashaPrettyWoman.html
```

Работать эти правила не будут.

---

### 3. Замена

[image: Замена] Почему вообще возник этот вопрос? я производил настройки `.htaccess` на [**WAMP-серверe**](http://www.wampserver.com/ru/) → перенёс сайт на GitHub Pages → всё заработало, я уверился в заблуждении, что из-за моего `.htaccess`. Однако в действительности `.htaccess` ни при чём:

#### 1. index.html в корневой папке сайта на заглавной

Чтобы при переходе на заглавную страницу сайта, к примеру, **`http://sashagoddess.com`**, отображалось бы содержимое файла **`http://sashagoddess.com/index.html`**. Это на GitHub Pages [**по умолчанию**](https://habrahabr.ru/post/316790/#comment_9945644).

#### 2. Скрытие расширения .html в URL

Чтобы при переходе по адресу **`http://sashagoddess.com/sashafantastic`** открывалась бы та же страница, что и при открытии URL **`http://sashagoddess.com/sashafantastic.html`**. Также доступно [**по умолчанию**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29200325/5951529).

#### 3. Пользовательская страница ошибки 404

[**Настраивается по-другому**](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site/).

---

На GitHub Pages в некоторых случаях вполне можно найти замену правилам `.htaccess`.