# Создание хоткея для выделения текста в форме ввода поисковой системы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Допустим, имеется пользовательская поисковая система на движке [**Google Custom Search Engine**](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/?hl=ru). [**URL-адрес**](http://kristinita.ru/technical_texts/TestSearch). А её код состоит только из скрипта от Google:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '008959915961530481423:nigd_brnqzu';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

У меня в браузере открыта вкладка со страницей, где расположен скрипт этой поисковой системы, а курсор находится в любом из браузерных полей ввода, например, `search bar` или `address bar`. Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на, например, <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+K</kbd> в любом распространённом браузере выделялся бы текст в форме ввода этой поисковой системы (или если его нет, курсор устанавливался бы в начало формы).

Пример: у меня открыта страница Википедии, а мой курсор находится в `address bar`. я нажимаю [сочетание](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Keyboard_shortcuts#List_of_access_keys) <kbd>Alt+Shift+F</kbd> → курсор переносится в поле поиска по Википедии, выделяя при этом текст, если он там есть.

[image: Sasha Princess Википедия]

Только нужно в форму ввода моей поисковой системы, а не Википедии. В открытой HTML-странице, где располагается данный скрипт поисковой системы, будет много элементов, но форма ввода текста только одна, от этой самой пользовательской поисковой системы.

[image: SashaPrincess Custom Search]

Какие перепробованные варианты не подходят.

1. Установка дополнений, аддонов и пр. на стороне клиента. Пользователи поисковой системы не должны ничего устанавливать со своей стороны, им нужно только нажать <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+K</kbd> в любом из распространённых браузеров.
2. Атрибут [*accesskey*](https://webref.ru/html/attr/accesskey). В представленном выше коде нет тегов `input`, `textarea` или пр., лишь скрипт от Google. *accesskey* некуда вставлять.
3. Сочетания <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> и <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd> в браузерах. Да, есть технологии вроде [**OpenSearch**](http://www.opensearch.org/Home), но

   1. В Search Bar у пользователей наверняка будет открыта другая поисковая система,
   2. Установка поисковой системы в Search Bar потребует лишнее движение от пользователя,
   3. Для переключения между поисковыми системами в Search Bar пользователю понадобится нажимать на браузерное сочетание горячих клавиш несколько раз.
4. Клавиша <kbd>Tab</kbd>. На странице с поисковой системой будет много элементов: <kbd>Tab</kbd> придётся нажимать много раз, переход к форме ввода осуществится не сразу.

Что можно сделать для создания шортката? Сайт, где находится поисковая система, статический, технологии кроме HTML и JavaScript, [**видимо**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/498520/199934), не поддерживаются.

Comment: В Google Chrome v.49 при фокусе `address bar` и при нажатии комбинации `Alt+Shift+F` фокус на пользовательский поиск не переходит. В мозилле фокус переводится. В википедии на пользовательском поиске стоит `accesskey="f"`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, решение только для Firefox лучше отсутствия решений вообще) .

Comment: Посмотрите мой измененный ответ. Работает в точности как у википедии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите на данные решения. Может, они вам помогут.

### Вариант 1

Вешаем обработчик события `keydown` на весь документ.

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/w5rmzg4e/2/):

```js
$(document).on("keydown", function($event) {
  if ($event.altKey && $event.ctrlKey && $event.keyCode == 75) {
    $('#gsc-i-id1').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '008959915961530481423:nigd_brnqzu';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
<div>
  Try press <code>Ctrl+Alt+K</code> when input on focus.
  <div>
    <input>
    <input type="button" value="OK">
  </div>
</div>
```

### Вариант 2

Также возможно сделать как в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0), через установку `accesskey` на пользовательский поиск.

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/gsj32ks0/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setAccessKey() {
    if ($('#gsc-i-id1').length === 0)
      setTimeout(setAccessKey, 500);
    else
      $('#gsc-i-id1').attr('accesskey', 'k');
  }
  setTimeout(setAccessKey, 500); // Нужно, потому что поиск от Google может загрузиться позже страницы
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '008959915961530481423:nigd_brnqzu';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
<div>
  Try press <pre>
  Internet Explorer: Alt + K
  Chrome: Alt + K or Shift + Alt + K
  Opera: Shift + Esc, K
  Safari: Alt + K
  Firefox: Shift + Alt + K
  </pre>
  when input on focus.
  <div>
    <input accesskey="j">
    <input type="button" value="OK">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Но если курсор находится в `address bar` или `search bar` браузера, то после нажатия на шорткат курсор не перемещается в поле ввода поисковой системы. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, к сожалению это так. Поскольку, когда курсор находится в `address bar` или `search bar`, то документ теряет фокус. А раз он теряет фокус, то события клавиатуры не обрабатываются. Так же не будет работать, если весь браузер не в фокусе(не активный).

Comment: @СашаЧерных, стоит выйти из вьюпорта браузера и `JS` бессилен, ибо техника безопасности. Могло бы помочь расширение, там есть назначение особых комбинаций клавиш, но только для хрома (возможно и в других браузерах, если там есть подобное) и только после установки.

Comment: Да, расширения помогут. Но, как было сказано в вопросе - *Установка дополнений, аддонов и пр. на стороне клиента. Пользователи поисковой системы не должны ничего устанавливать со своей стороны, им нужно только нажать Ctrl+Alt+K в любом из распространённых браузеров.*

Comment: @Other, а это вряд ли и нужно, чтобы хоткей функционировал, когда браузер не в фокусе. Нигде и не видел такого. Уточнил вопрос.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, работа в `FF` - скорее исключение, чем правило. В хроме и `IE9` не наблюдается работы `accesskey`, если окно не в фокусе. В других браузерах не проверял. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey

Comment: В Опере и Хроме форма поиска несколько секунд загружается. В Firefox всё работает отлично. Спасибо.

Comment: Видимо, в Firefox  у Вас уже закешировались необходимые подгружаемые скрипты для пользовательского поиска. Если ответ верный, пожалуйста примите его.

Comment: Прошу прощения, загрузка в несколько секунд была вызвана конфликтом с другим скриптом, после удаления которого со страницы видимого торможения у меня больше не наблюдается. Спасибо! Не работает в Opera и Chrome, но работает в Firefox и Internet Explorer.